# waiting for cookie in Cypress spec

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have problem with reading cookie in my Cypress test

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('cookie', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.setCookie('abc', 'def');
    });

    it('read', () => {
        let cookieValue: string;
        cy.getCookie('abc').should('exist').then(c => cookieValue = c.value);
        cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('not.equal', undefined);
    });
});
```

I have error from last `should`:
**expected undefined to not equal undefined**

[image: Cypress console]

**Edit 1**

My aim is to have cookie value synchronically. I managed to have working code:

```
  let cookieValue: string;
  it('read', async () => {
    cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('equal', undefined);
    cookieValue = await new Promise(resolve => cy.getCookie('abc').should('exist').then(c => resolve(c.value)));
    cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('not.equal', undefined);
  });
```

but it doesn't look cypress-way. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the cookie in a variable at the same time as setting it

```js
describe('cookie', () => {
   let cookieValue: string;

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.setCookie('abc', 'def');
        cookieValue = 'def'
    });

    it('read', () => {
        cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('not.equal', undefined);
    });
});
```

If the cookie is already set going in to the test, extracting in beforeEach block gives you a synchronous value.

```js
describe('cookie', () => {
   let cookieValue: string;

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.getCookie('abc').should('exist')
          .then(c => cookieValue = c.value);
    });

    it('read', () => {
        cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('not.equal', undefined);
    });
});
```

Comment: I ended with the solution: storing cookie value in `beforeEach` into environment variable

Answer (score 1):

The Cypress commands are async, you need to wrap and test inside the `.then()`

```js
cy.getCookie('abc').should('exist').then(c => 
  cookieValue = c.value
  cy.wrap(cookieValue).should('not.equal', undefined);
);
```

More precisely, Cypress commands run in a queue, but `cy.wrap(cookieValue)` will take the value of `cookieValue` before the queue runs, i.e it has the original empty value when enqueued.

---

You can synchronously get all the cookies related to test document using plain javascript.

Since the return value is a string you may need to parse more complex values such as objects.

```js
const document = cy.state('document')
const cookieValue = document.cookie
  .split('; ')
  .find(row => row.startsWith('abc='))
  ?.split('=')[1];
```

---

You can also await `cy.now()`

```js
it('takes the cookie', async () => {
  const cookieObject = await cy.now('getCookie', 'abc')
  /* Properties
    domain: "localhost"
    expiry: 2287046766
    httpOnly: false
    name: "abc"
    path: "/"
    secure: false
    value: "my-cookie-value"
  */
  const cookieValue = cookieObject.value
```

Comment: It works. But I need to have the cookie value available outside `then`. Thus my idea with waiting for it. I edited my question.

Comment: How did that go? I think I tried that before without result.

Comment: what do you mean "that" ?

Comment: Your Promise idea.

Comment: It looks promising (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias `as` to save the cookie value and `then` access it outside then like this. One thing to remember is the aliases will work within the same test, because cypress clears aliases between tests. If you want to access the value throughout the tests, I would suggest you to use `Cypress.env()`, explained below.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('cookie', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.setCookie('abc', 'def')
  })

  it('read', () => {
    let cookieValue: string
    cy.getCookie('abc')
      .should('exist')
      .then((c) => {
        cy.wrap(c.value).as('cookieValue')
      })
    cy.get('@cookieValue').then((cookieValue) => {
      expect(cookieValue).to.not.be.undefined
    })
  })
})
```

You can also use `Cypress.env` to globally save the cookie value and use it anywhere throughout the project.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('cookie', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.setCookie('abc', 'def')
  })

  it('read', () => {
    let cookieValue: string
    cy.getCookie('abc')
      .should('exist')
      .then((c) => {
        Cypress.env('cookieValue', c.value)
      })
    cy.wrap(Cypress.env('cookieValue')).should('not.equal', undefined)
  })
})
```